# Can not invoke filter method on stream

Tags: java, filter, lambda, predicate

i'm getting confused while doing tutorial @Java SE 8 from Oracel 
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html

I stucked @Lambda Expressions and Collections - while trying to filter list of Persons using filter. Mine getCriteria() method from SearchCriteria returns back Predicate while filter accepts Predicate - where is mistake ?

Thanks for helping me

SearchCriteria.class

```
    private final Map<String, Predicate<Person>> searchMap = new HashMap<>();

private SearchCriteria() {
    super();
    initSearchMap();
}

public static SearchCriteria getInstance() {
    return new SearchCriteria();
}

private void initSearchMap() {

    Predicate<Person> allDrivers = p -> p.getAge() >= 16;
    Predicate< Person> allDraftees = p -> p.getAge() >= 18 && p.getAge() <= 25;
    Predicate< Person> allPilots = p -> p.getAge() >= 23 && p.getAge() <= 65;

    searchMap.put("allDrivers", allDrivers);
    searchMap.put("allDraftees", allDraftees);
    searchMap.put("allPilots", allPilots);
}

public Predicate<Person> getCriteria(String predicateName) {

    Predicate<Person> result;
    result = searchMap.get(predicateName);

    // result = searchMap.get(predicateName);
    // Optional<Predicate<Person>> optPredicatePerson =
    // Optional.of(searchMap.get(predicateName));

    // if (optPredicatePerson.isPresent()) {
    // result = optPredicatePerson.get();
    // }

    // Predicate<Person> z = p -> false;
    //
    // optPredicatePerson.orElse(z);

    // return result;

    if (result == null) {
        System.out.println("Search Criteria not found... ");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

public static void main(String ... args){

```
    List<Person> pl = Person.createShortList();

    SearchCriteria search = SearchCriteria.getInstance();
    System.out.println("\n=== Western Pilot Phone List ===");

    pl.stream().filter(search.getCriteria("allPilots")).forEach(Person::printWesterName);
```

}

Comment: looks good to me- what's the question?

Comment: I get error which says The method filter(Predicate<? super Person>) in the type Stream<Person> is not applicable for the arguments (Predicate<Person>)